# showing that there is no simple group of order 48

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I tried to solve this prob. by using Sylow theorems.
But i can't solve it because it is not seen in the text as a example or exercise.

I even use a diagram of sets and consider all possible cases,  but it is not effective....

Comment: One easy way is to use Burnside's Theorem :).

Comment: Is it contained in the graduate course? I have not heard the burnside 'theorem'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose G is simple. Since G is simple, we must have that $n_2 = 3$. Let P be a Sylow 2-subgroup of G. Then $|G:N_G(P)|=3$.

**Theorem:** If G is a simple group, $|G|\neq 2$, and if $H<G, |G:H|=n > 1$ then $G\cong$ subgroup of $A_n$.

So in our case we have that $G\cong$ subgroup of $A_3$ but $|A_3|=3$ and $|G|=48$, which is a contradiction. Thus G cannot be simple.

**Proof of Theorem:**
Let G be a simple group, $|G|>2$. Let $H<G$ and $|G:H|=n>1$. There exists a homomorphism $\theta :G \to S_n$ with $ker(\theta)\subseteq H$ (the permutation representation of the G acting on cosets H of G by left multiplication).

Since G is simple, we must have that $ker(\theta) = 1$. So $\theta (G) \cong G$ by the isomorphism theorem.

Suppose that the result is not true, that $\theta(G) \nsubseteq A_n$. Then we must have $A_n\theta(G) = S_n$. 
Since $\frac{S_n}{A_n} = \frac{A_n\theta(G)}{A_n}\cong \frac{\theta(G)}{A_n\cap\theta(G)}$ by the second isomorphism theorem, and G is simple, we must have $A_n\cap \theta(G)=1$ or $\theta(G)$.

If $A_n\cap \theta(G)= \theta(G)$, then $S_n/A_n=1$, which is a contradiction.

In the case $A_n\cap \theta(G)=1$ we have that $S_n/A_n \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cong \theta(G)\cong G$, i.e. that $|G|=2$, which is a contradiction.

Thus we must have that $\theta(G)\subseteq A_n$

Comment: sorry but.. Is the theorem that you remark in a graduate course??
I have not seen the theorem in undergraduate....

Comment: Yes, I will provide a proof.

Comment: By the way, why did AnΘ(G)=Sn hold? Also, how can An ∩ Θ(G)=G holds??? The left in the equality is a subset of Sn, which is different to G....

Comment: one more question~ Does your definition of permutation act on RIGHT cosets of H ??
I think if you mean left coset, then the kernel of Θ may not be contained in H...

Comment: Left cosets with the action being multiplication on the left. The $A_n\cap \theta(G) = G$ was a typo and should be $A_n\cap \theta(G) = \theta(G)$, which I fixed.

Comment: When the LEFT coset is choosed, i can't check the kernel of theta is contained in H. A

Comment: In the group G/H of left cosets, if gxH=xH then $gxx^{-1}=g\in H$ so the kernel is contained in H.

Comment: If gxH=xH, then $x^{-1}g^{-1}x$ $\in$ $H$ ??

Comment: $gxH=xH => (gxH)(x^{-1}H)=(xH)(x^{-1}H) => gxx^{-1}H = H$

Comment: Because H is not a normal subgroup of G(∵G:simple), I think that the cosets of H in G may not be a group.
Therefore, the existance of inverse of $xH$ is not guaranteed..

Comment: My mistake, you are correct in that H need not be normal. For an element g to be in the kernel of $\theta$, we must have that gxH=xH $\forall x \in G$. This is equivalent to $g\in xHx^{-1} \forall x\in G$. So we must have $g\in \cap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1}$, and in particular that $g\in H$.

Comment: Now I understand your explain completely. 
Thank you for your greaaaaaat help. :)

Answer (score 8):

If $|G|=48=2^4 3$, then $n_2 \in \{1,3\}.$ If $n_2 = 1,$ the group is not simple. If $n_2 = 3$ and $G$ is simple, then the action of $G$ on the Sylow 2 subgroups induces a homomorphism into $S_3$ which must have a trivial kernel. This implies that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_3,$ which is of course too small of a group to contain $G$.

Comment: um......what means 'the action of G in the Sylow 2 subgroups induces a homomorphism into S3 which must have a tirivial kernel'??    
I don't understand how can i find the homomorphism into S3....

Comment: @JeongNam-ho : $G$ acts on the set of 2-sylow subgroups by conjugation. If there are 3 2-sylow subgroups, this will give the required homomorphism.

Comment: @JeongNam-ho: Are you taking a graduate course in Algebra at the time? The concept of group actions is fundamental to the Sylow theorems, and the fact that conjugating the Sylow subgroups preserves the size and thus forms a group action on $Syl_p(G)$ is an extremely helpful strategy for solving these Sylow problems.

If $G$ acts on a set $\Omega$, there is a homomorphism $\phi : G \to \Omega$ defined by $\phi(g)$ is the function sending $\omega \in \Omega$ to $g \cdot \omega \in \Omega$. That this forms a well defined homomorphism is readily verified.

Comment: I mean $\phi: G \to Sym(\Omega)$, rather than $\phi: G \to \Omega$ in the above paragraph.

Comment: ahhh~~ Now I realized what you mean. Just the shortage of my english skill disturbs my understanding.Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without Sylow, if you want to. Consider conjugacy classes. The allowed sizes must divide $48$: $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$, $16$, $3$, $6$, $12$, $24$, and $48$. The identity must be in a class by itself. So now we have $47$ elements to pack into classes; and because that's odd, there must be a class of size $1$ or $3$.

Say there's an element $x$ with conjugacy class of size $1$, then it's in the center. Then $\langle x \rangle$ is normal. We either have a normal subgroup, in which case $G$ is not simple, or the entire group, meaning $G$ is cyclic. But a cyclic group of size $48$ can't be simple.

Say there's an element $x$ with conjugacy class of size $3$, then we can create a homomorphism to $S_3$. The size of the image is at most $6$, so the kernel is at least size $8$. Verify that the kernel isn't the whole group. Kernels of homomorphisms are normal subgroups, so we have a non-trivial normal subgroup, making $G$ not simple.

Source: Forced to find all simple groups up to order $60$, no Sylow allowed. Don't try $30$ or $56$ like that.

Comment: why do you assert that there must be a class of size 1 or 3?? Also, why is it sufficient just to consider the cases size 1 and 3?

Comment: If $47$ is a sum of a bunch of integers, at least one is odd, and those two are the only odd ones. (Edited the OP too)

Comment: ohh i see.. Thank you very much!!:)

Comment: Sorry but, I have one more question. In the third paragraph, the homomorphsim that you create is one in the Passa's answer above??

Comment: No, it's not quite the same homomorphism.

For his, take a subgroup $H$, and all its cosets. An element $g \in G$ permutes the cosets around by left multiplication (i.e., it sends $A$ to $gA$). So it's a homomorphism into $S_n$ where $n$ is the number of cosets of $H$.

For mine, $g$ permutes the elements of the conjugacy class $\mathcal{C}$. It sends $b \in \mathcal{C}$ to $gbg^{-1}$. It is a homomorphism into $S_n$, where $n$ is the size of the conjugacy class.

Comment: ahh~~ I had a mistake for understanding your expalin.
But your last expain is clear. Thanks a lot!